# How immutable objects' memory cleared?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, immutability

I have some questions-

1. As string constant pool is present in the heap memory and GC collects garbage from heap memory.
2. Does it cleans the string constant pool as well, according to my info it does not.
3. Then how does constant pool memory is cleared ?
4. How to detect immutable classes of java and where it's objects are stored ?

Please give some details regarding this.

Detail working of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The string pool is just a data structure containing references to `String` instances. These references have the same semantics as a [weak reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), so they are cleared when no other reference to the object exists.

Since common garbage collectors work by traversing the graph of still reachable objects, it’s not hard to implement such semantic. All it has to do, is to check after the traversal whether the referent has been encountered during the traversal. If not, the weak reference is cleared.

There is no special relevance to “immutable classes” to the JVM and hence, no code to detect them. To the JVM, immutable objects are just objects.

Comment: Short and precise answer!

Answer (score 1):

Garbage Collection
Before Java 7, the JVM placed the Java String Pool in the PermGen space, which has a fixed size — it can’t be expanded at runtime and is not eligible for garbage collection.

The risk of interning Strings in the PermGen (instead of the Heap) is that we can get an OutOfMemory error from the JVM if we intern too many Strings.

From Java 7 onwards, the Java String Pool is stored in the Heap space, which is garbage collected by the JVM. The advantage of this approach is the reduced risk of OutOfMemory error because unreferenced Strings will be removed from the pool, thereby releasing memory.

The objects are stored in heap memory, but the reference to the object is stored in the stack memory. The string pool is the special place inside the head memory where all the string literals reside, whenever the reference is
to the string literal deleted, Here deleted means all the reference, as multiple references can point same string literal Or simply there do not exist any reference to the String literal then it get removed by the Garbage collector.

For more details on how String constant poll works and how the memory management works, Please follow the below articles.

1> [How String pool works and how references are stored in stack memory and multiple references are possible?](https://www.scaler.com/topics/java/string-pool-in-java/)

2> [How memory management works in string constant pool?](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool#:%7E:text=From%20Java%207%20onwards%2C%20the,the%20pool%2C%20thereby%20releasing%20memory.)

If you find the article helpful please upvote, This is my first answer and it will give me confidence to contribute more on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You should not rely on baeldung.com, lots of articles there are of a poor quality. Interned strings were always subject to garbage collection; the PermGen is irrelevant. But code containing string literals will keep references to the strings independently of the pool, which means that those strings can not get garbage collected as long as the code is alive, even after Java 7. And the string pool is not stored in stack memory. Neither of the two articles says something like that.